# how to use import form another project in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I want to use a import from one of my other projects in Android Studio. In one class I use:

```
import com.example.SettingsProvider;
```

In Eclipse it works, if the second project is also open, but I did not find a way to do this in Android Studio, Thank you for you Help

Boe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't "just work" in Eclipse. You have to actually define the other project as dependency of the one in which you want to use the class. It's the same thing in Android Studio it looks just a little different.

Go to your app module in the project explorer and right click and pick "Open Module Settings". Alternatively you can just click on the module in the project explorer and press <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Then select the tab "Dependencies", click the plus at the bottom or top left depending on your OS and add a module dependency.

Comment: It sounds good for me, but when I want to add it i get 'Found no modules to depend on'

Comment: Do you have more than one module in your project?

Comment: I found a way to fix it, i have to add it into 'Sources' then it works. Toke some time but you help me :-)

Answer (score -1):

**Import into Android Studio**

1.In Android Studio, select File > Import Project.

2.Locate a project you exported from Eclipse, select the project's root directory and click OK.

3.Select Create project from existing sources and click Next.

4.Follow the walk-through to complete the import process.

for more info [clickhere](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html#Export)

some FAQ [Eclipse Migration FAQ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html)

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking about migrating the project.

Comment: you are right Xaver Kapeller, it has nothing to do with migration